# MS Word / OpenXML: extracting grammar and spelling errors

Tags: vba, ms-word, openxml, spell-checking

InOpenXMLthere is the [`w:proofErr` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.prooferror(v=office.14).aspx) which can be of spelling type (attributes `w:type="spellStart"` and `w:type="spellEnd"`) or of grammar type (attributes `w:type="gramStart"` and `w:type="gramEnd"`). I need to extract errors of my document (both types), when I created a small test document (just one sentence with two errors), the information was indeed in the `.docx` XML file, but when I saved the whole text I need to process (a 5MB file), the information was not included in the `.docx` file (probably Word considers that in large documents this would be too much noise in the XML data).

How can I extract this information even in big files?

Is there some way to force MS Word to include the information in the `.docx` file?

If not, is there some VBA script that can mark spelling errors and grammar errors with, for example, a different color or some special character, so that the information becomes **hardcoded** into the file?

Here is an example, for the sentence "The children plays in the guarden" (which has an agreement error and a spelling error):

```
     <w:t>The children </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E17B0">
    <w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>plays</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E17B0">
    <w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> in the </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E17B0">
    <w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>guarden</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/> 
<w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E17B0">
    <w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>.</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I would like to obtain, for example, "The children ▶plays◀ in the *guarden*"